# Typecasting in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert

I have 2 tables:

- `table1` (name text, rollno int)
- `table2` (r text)

I want to convert `rollno` to text and insert into table2.

This is what i tried, it says explicit conversion is not allowed:

```
insert into table2 
    select convert (text, rollno) 
    from table1;
```

Comment: You should NOT be using TEXT or NTEXT - those are very obsolete and deprecated datatypes!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `convert(varchar, rollno)` instead

Comment: cant i convert it to text?

Comment: It will implicitly convert into text once converted into varchar. There is no direct conversion int->text